# Converting MP3 to WAV with low file size

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

i successfully convert MP3 file to WAV but the problem is my MP3 File size is 53mb and when i convert it to WAV the file size is 250mb, is there a way to make it lower or same file size as possible as mp3?

i don't have problem on my code so i guess i won't post it, but if you want to see i might edit question for code.

i don't have an idea dude...

```
        using(Mp3FileReader mp3 = new Mp3FileReader(open.FileName))
        {
            using (WaveStream pcm = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(mp3))
            {
                WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(save.FileName, pcm);
            }
        }
```

smaller file size is the answer what i want, i choose WAV audio format because it's a requirement for the app i am making.

Comment: If you are going to make the file size lower, you are going to lose quality.

Comment: @AliBahraminezhad i just want knowledge sir i don't mind. tell me please!

Comment: An mp3 file to a wav file is equivalent of a zip file to a text file.  The text file may be 100MB in size but the zip file only 1MB.  However, when you unzip the zip file (which you *have* to do to make it a text file again), it will become 100MB again.  The only way to change that is to remove some of the content, making the text file less than it was.  This is merely an analogy.  The real question is *why* you want to do this.  Does it serve a purpose to have a small wav file from an mp3 file?

Comment: @Archer for optimizing my game.
console app (.net Core) game

Comment: This is an example of an XY Problem, where you ask us how to achieve your solution, when it's actually the wrong thing to do to resolve the real problem.   MP3 is how you optimise audio for file size without losing much (if any) quality.  Converting to a small wav would literally be the wrong thing to do.  If you want to make the file smaller then you need to change it to a lower bitrate, which is what the answer below actually did.

Comment: I suggest you modify the question to explain what the problem is, rather than your attempt at a solution.  Then we can vote for the answer below to be undeleted as it was actually correct.

Comment: yes,my question has been answered a while ago but he delete it. i convert it to WAV because console app(.net.core) only supports WAV, someone claim MP3 can be played in it but. it a little bit tricky for me and i stop and think another way.

Comment: Have a look at this... https://github.com/mobiletechtracker/NetCoreAudio

Comment: @Archer thank you for making my project more easy. i love you, no homo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As MP3 compress the audio, your WAV file will always be larger than your MP3 file. So if you want a lower WAV file size, you need to change your WAV file to a lower bitrate **but you will loose quality**.

You have to find the best compromise between your audio quality and the file size.

The following code is an example changing the bitrate of an MP3 file. **You have to adapt it on your case depending the quality you want**:

```
using (var mp3Reader = new Mp3FileReader(inputFile))
{
  var wavFormat = new WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1);
  using (var wavStream = new WaveFormatConversionStream(wavFormat, mp3Reader))
  {
    WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(outputFile, wavStream);
  }
}
```